# Eclipse Git Plugin: cannot Configure Push To Upstream

Tags: git, eclipse-plugin

In eclipse, I have a project that connected with git repository. I can commit & remote push but the option: Team -> Remote -> "Configure Fetch from Upstream" and "Configure Push To Upstream" are disabled/grayed.

[image]

What actually happened??

How to enable them?

Comment: you didn't  set a upsteam for that branch

Answer (score 28):

Here's what I did and this worked fine:

1. Right click your project, choose Team→Show in Repositories View. You
   will switch perspectives and be in the Git Repositories tab.
2. Right-click "Remotes" and choose "Create Remote". For "Remote name",
   enter "origin". Check "Configure Fetch" and "Check Configure Push". Click OK.
3. Click Change. Enter your repo URL information as
   you did during your initial push. Click Save. You should now be able
   to push by merely right-clicking on your project, then Team→Push to
   Upstream.

Because the remote was added under the project in question, each project can have its own upstream origin and they will not interfere (whereas the Window > Preferences solution is a global setting).

Based on your description of what you did, it appears you attempted this - but possibly did not use the name "origin" for the remote, which is absolutely necessary.